# Проблема с многомерными массивами JS, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, массивы

В ходе работы с двумерными массивами столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

```
arr = [[0, 0], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2]]
if (arr[1] == [1, 0]) {   // false
    alert('true');
}
else {
    alert('false');
}
```

Код выводит false. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы проверка проходила правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы проверяете ссылочные типы данных на равенство. Такого рода проверки хороши для примитивных типов: `String`, `Number`, `null`, `undefined`, `Boolean`.

Сравнивая массивы или объекты, надо сравнивать их полностью по значениям внутри них, обходя каждое значение по эквивалентному адресу.
Если ваш двумерный массив представляет массив из массивов чисел, то корректной будет проверка на

```
arr[1].toString() === [1, 0].toString()
```

Этот способ крайне не универсальный и подойдет только для вашего случая

Если вы уверены, что ваши массивы [JSON безопасны](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46416370/what-is-a-json-safe-object), можно провернуть такое

```
JSON.stringify(arr[1]) === JSON.stringify([1, 0])
```

В случае тяжелых объектов и массивов - это очень дорогая по времени исполнения операция.

Comment: А что делать в случае использования indexOf или inArray в JQuery?

Comment: сформулируйте вопрос понятнее

Comment: Исходное условие такое: Boolean($.inArray([1, 0], arr) + 1)

Comment: Это выражение всегда будет `false` так как вы сравниваете не значение, типа `5 === 5`, а ссылки в памяти компьютера. И новосозданный массив `[1, 0]` получит другую ссылку в памяти, чем уже имеющийся `arr`

Comment: А как в таком случае проверить?

Comment: Если способы, которые я описал, вам не подходят, то смотрите в другой части своего кода, почему вам приходится именно так проверять равенство. Возможно, нужно в другом месте кода сохранить значение элемента массива в переменной и потом сравнивать.

Comment: Мне нужно проверить, есть ли такой элемент в массиве

Comment: Я уже описал, как можно проверить значения выше, пробуйте

Comment: Хорошо. Спасибо